# Django query based on ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am new to Python and Django.

I am trying to build myself very simple blog application.
So I have this 2 models :

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Blogpost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = tinymce_models.HTMLField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

As you can see Blogpost can contain many Tags,
my question is how can I query `Blogpost.objects.all()` to get Blogposts list by specific Tag?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [related manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) is your answer

```
t = Tag.objects.get(name="Some tag")
t.blogpost_set.all()
```